# How to dynamically specify a table name in MySQL select statement?

Tags: mysql

I am working with MySQLpersistence in OpenHAB. It creates one table called Items with two columns: ItemID (Int), ItemName (VarChar).
It creates a table for each item. For example, Item1 has two columns (Time, Value).
It does this for each Item number in the Items table.

I want to be able to select the Item tables based on a query of the Items table.

Except this does not work - it just gives me the list of Item# names...

```
mysql> select *  from (select CONCAT("Item",y.ItemID) as TName from Items y  where ItemName like 'F%F') x;
+--------+
| TName  |
+--------+
| Item3  |
| Item5  |
| Item26 |
| Item28 |
| Item29 |
| Item30 |
| Item31 |
| Item32 |
| Item33 |
+--------+
9 rows in set (0.06 sec)


--------------------------------------

mysql> describe Items;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ItemId   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ItemName | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from Items limit 3;
+--------+-----------------+
| ItemId | ItemName        |
+--------+-----------------+
|      1 | OS_ChickenDoor  |
|      2 | FF_Kitchen_Wall |
|      3 | F2_LabF         |
+--------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> Describe Item1;
+-------+----------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field | Type           | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+-------+----------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Time  | datetime       | NO   | PRI | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| Value | varchar(20000) | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
+-------+----------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Is this a good idea?

Comment: Table names cannot be expressions. The only way to do it is by generating dynamic SQL in a stored procedure, executing it with `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`.

Comment: This is horrible table design. If OpenHab forces this design, I expect it provides an API for using it, because you can't do it easily with SQL.